# zpool didn't increase after adding disk slice

Tags: solaris, zpool

i added formatted 3 different slices from a disk and added to a zpool but i didn't increase his size.
This is the pool size before adding the slide

```
root@snr-hosting-bta-02:~# zfs list z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1 
NAME                                          USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1  1.43T  44.1G  1.43T  legacy
```

Added a 600mb to the pool:

```
root@snr-hosting-bta-02:~# zpool add  z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1 c0t6006016028603000F5380411E5BEE511d0s0
```

Verify the addition:

```
root@snr-hosting-bta-02:~# zpool status z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1
  pool: z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c0t6006016028603000A632E26E77AEE511d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c0t60060160286030004B78DD56EF2CE611d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

But the size didn't increase at all as you can see:

```
root@snr-hosting-bta-02:~# zpool list z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1
NAME                                          SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CAP  DEDUP      HEALTH  ALTROOT
z3363af79-edf5-474e-9568-4922eafee28b-data1  1.49T  1.43T  68.6G  95%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Any help of what could happen?

Comment: There is no evidence the pool size didn't grow in your post. In any case, 600 MB is negligible compared to 1.49 T.

Comment: Hello jiliagre, you're right and make me realise my mistake, the size supposed to be 600G and i made the partition of 600M :(.
Could i expand the partition without any damage to the Zpool?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't expand the partition without damage to the pool (just expand the pool to fill all available space afterwards) *as long as all you do is grow the partition without touching the data in any way*, but I wouldn't want to do it without testing it in a staging environment first...

Comment: Hello all! I managed to work the situation in this way:
I use a disk available to replace the wrong partitioned slice of the pool with the new slice.
I partitioned again the disk and replace again the site with the right partition of the right disk.